# javafx listview null pointer when selecting item

Tags: java, listview, javafx, combobox

I'm, trying to perform an action when choosing an item from a list view (currently I do have a comboBox working but I'd like to change it to a listView or anything of the sort that can display selectable items in a form of a list, if you have any ideas of different controls I'm open to ideas)

Anyways, I have a listView with a property change method in order to perform a certain action when selecting an item from the list. I also have a different method that refreshed the list. When I click on the refresh button and try to select an item from the list, I get a null pointer to the lw.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem(). I've tried countering this by doing an if statement, doesn't work.

```
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1)  {
    if(arr != null || arr.length > 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            cmBox.getItems().add(arr[i]);
            lw.getItems().add(arr[i]);
        }
    }

    lw.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            if(lw.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() == null) {
                lw.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
            }
            String selectedString = lw.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            String[] conParts = selectedString.split("@");
            String selectedConName = conParts[0];
            number = conParts[1];
            selectedName = selectedConName;
            displayTF(selectedName);
        }
    });
}
```

for comparison, this is the method that works with the comboBox:

```
public void pickContact(ActionEvent event) {
    if(cmBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() == -1) {
        return;
    }
    String selectedString = arr[cmBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()];
    String[] conParts = selectedString.split("@");
    String selectedConName = conParts[0];
    number = conParts[1];
    selectedName = selectedConName;
    displayTF(selectedName);
}
```

Also, this is the refreshing method:

```
public void reloadCmBox(ActionEvent event) {
    cmBox.getItems().clear();
    arr = sqld.selectAll();
    cmBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(Arrays.asList(arr)));
    cmBox.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();

    lw.getItems().clear();
    lw.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(Arrays.asList(arr)));
    cmBox.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
}
```

If you wonder, this is the fxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="409.0" prefWidth="535.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.CVController">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="tf" layoutX="325.0" layoutY="75.0" />
      <Button layoutX="325.0" layoutY="141.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#placeCall" text="Call" />
      <Button fx:id="sendText" layoutX="367.0" layoutY="141.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#sendText" text="Text" />
      <Button fx:id="OpenConEditor" layoutX="412.0" layoutY="141.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openConEditer" text="Edit" />
      <Button layoutX="458.0" layoutY="141.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#deleteCon" text="Delete" />
      <Button fx:id="OpenConCreator" layoutX="483.0" layoutY="75.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openConAdder" text="New" />
      <ComboBox fx:id="cmBox" layoutX="93.0" layoutY="74.0" onAction="#pickContact" prefHeight="28.0" prefWidth="223.0" />
      <Label layoutX="231.0" layoutY="20.0" prefHeight="28.0" prefWidth="149.0" text="Contacts View">
         <font>
            <Font size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Button fx:id="SDTomer" layoutX="77.0" layoutY="162.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#speedDial" text="Tomer" />
      <Label layoutX="77.0" layoutY="133.0" text="Speed Dial">
         <font>
            <Font size="16.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Button layoutX="46.0" layoutY="75.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#reloadCmBox" text="R" />
      <ListView fx:id="lw" layoutX="153.0" layoutY="187.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: a) why not simply use "newValue"? b) I am not so sure if it is a good idea to change the property in a listener for that property(at least return ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should avoid doing something that modifies a property from a listener to that property. Calling `selectFirst` is such a thing.

Also note that the selected item can be changed to `null`, if the selected item gets removed from the `items` list. There may not be an item to select at the time the listener is invoked. The best thing to do would probably be to simply ignore events like this (or at least using `Platform.runLater` after checking for a non-empty items list to select an element).

You can use `newValue` to get the updated value of the property you listen to btw.

```
lw.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
        if(newValue != null) {
            String[] conParts = newValue.split("@");
            String selectedConName = conParts[0];
            number = conParts[1];
            selectedName = selectedConName;
            displayTF(selectedName);
        }

    }
});
```